# Grouping problem: 32 items -> 8 groups -> min. 1 in each group : How many possibilities?

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to figure out how many possibilities are possible under these conditions:

I got 32 items (marbles) and need to place them into 8 groups where there's at least 1 marble in each group.

Also groups are labeled so the order matters: $[25,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]$ and $[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,25]$ are different.

Also what if a group could only have maximum of $8$ items.

How would anyone solve these? I don't even know where to start. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** Use the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Put $\sum_{i=1}^8x_i=32$. As $x_i\geq1$, we can write $\sum_{i=1}^8y_i=24$ where $0\leq y_i\leq7$.

So, the final answer should be $$\binom{24+8-1}{8-1}$$

**(b)** Use the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) along with the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Put $\sum_{i=1}^8x_i=32$. As $x_i\geq1$, we can write $\sum_{i=1}^8y_i=24$ where $0\leq y_i\leq7$.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, the final answer should be

$$\binom{24+8-1}{8-1}-\binom{8}{1}\binom{16+8-1}{8-1}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{8+8-1}{8-1}-\binom{8}{3}\binom{0+8-1}{8-1}$$

The second term arises by taking the case where $1$ box has over $8$ objects, the third term arises by taking the case where $2$ boxes have over $8$ objects, and the fourth term arises by taking the case where $3$ cases have over $8$ objects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!